# ¿Como actualizar campos mediante querie de bases de datos de servidores diferentes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Buen día, espero y me puedan ayudar. Tengo 2 Bases de datos que se encuentran en diferentes servidores, mi idea es actualizar unos campos mediante una consulta, sin embargo se encuentran en servidores diferentes, por ejemplo una base la tengo en un servidor terminación 192...120 y otra la tengo en 192....135, ¿hay alguna forma de poder hacer algo?.
Gracias.

Comment: Ni siquiera se pueden crear llaves foráneas entre bases de datos en SQL Server en el mismo servidor, menos aún entre servidores. La única opción sería usando triggers, lo que realmente no es recomendable

Comment: Lo que necesitas hacer es para únicamente consulta? o lo que quieres es generar una tabla en un servidor y que tenga clave foránea de una tabla en otro servidor?

Comment: Al decir relacionarlas, ¿Quieres crear llaves foráneas entre ellas o quieres hacer una consulta y que en ella realices la relación?

Comment: Les explico muy brevemente, tengo necesidad de insertar los datos que se encuentran en una tabla de otra base en un servidor, lo pienso hacer mediante consultas.

Comment: @Ric_hc podrías [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/93371/edit) e indicar que quieres hacer entre dichas tablas y que quieres hacerlo por consulta. Si es una consulta si se puede.

Comment: A ver.. quieres "copiar" los datos de una tabla desde un servidor y llevarlos a otra tabla en otro servidor?. Te sugiero que aclares bien esto en tu pregunta.

Comment: Ok. gracias, la he editado. Espero ser mas explicito en este momento.

Comment: Ah, bueno, claro, la pregunta ahora tiene otra connotación. Esto lo puedes hacer a través de servidores vinculados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con tu aclaración lo primero que necesitas es vincular la base mediante LinkServer a la cual necesitas acceder de forma remota.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego agregas la información necesaria de conexión hacia ese servidor, donde especificará el nombre con el cual llamaras a ese servidor.

Ya con ello podrás realizar tus consultas entre servidores, solo debes especificar el servidor de la tabla a la cual necesitas acceder de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT*
FROM [SERVIDOR].[BASE DE DATOS].[ESQUEMA].[TABLA]
```

Para ejemplo:

```
SELECT*
FROM Servidor.MiDB.Dbo.MiTable
```

Y si necesitas hacer consulta con alguna tabla de un servidor con el otros, como en un **JOIN**:

```
SELECT *
FROM MiTabla AS A
INNER JOIN Servidor.BaseDatos.Dbo.MiOtraTabla AS B
    ON (a.id = b.id)
```

Espero mi respuesta te haya ayudado, saludos.